# October CMS trouble with backend cache (?)

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I see a rather dangerous trouble in the october cms backend.

How it manifests itself:

I log into the backend as superuser, then edit another backend user, then log out of the superuser account.

After that, if I go from incognito or another browser to the page of the edited user, then the page for editing this user is available to everyone. That is, even without a login, I can see the backend/users/update/55 page, for example.

Such problems are observed only on two types of pages: the backend user and the rainlab preview user page. The rest of the pages, when you enter them without a login, are redirected to loginpage as needed.

The page and the data on it are shown, but at the same time I can not save anything or click, a token error pops up.

After 10 minutes, the page is no longer available to everyone.

Apparently, this situation is observed only with me. 3 sites on october cms on one server, memcached cache (prefixes for each site are different). Nginx + php.fpm.

What do you think is the reason for this behavior?

I think that the pages that are not logged in come from the cache, but I'm not sure. How to disable backend caching in october cms?

upd: october cms 469 build

Comment: I think its not related to October cms itself as It does not have backend caching up to my knowledge, it may be related to the server.. maybe try to check using those sites locally and if problem persists

Answer (score 0):

i can't comment following to Hardik, but i can confirm there is a cache on backend, cause i'm making a lot of changes on my plugin, and i need to wait at least one minute to see changes.

IMO, i think Hardik anwsers you well, i remember a bug when i was working on a shared hosting with CDN enabled. Maybe you have to look on your hosting configuration.

best,
Lucas